# How do I get Terms from termstore using SharePoint Framework?

Tags: taxonomy, term-store, office-365-developer, spfx, spfx-webparts

**I want to fetch terms from termstore, in my SharePoint Framework app.**

I have tried this microsoft sample:
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/knockout-taxonomy

I followed the instructions to get the sample to work. In local workbench I get mocked up data. When I try it in my developer-tentant **to get real data** I get the following **error**:

---

> *[SPWebPartErrorCode.ScriptLoadError]:: Det går inte att läsa in skriptresurser för webbdelen
>   WebPart.undefined.0860422e-6848-427c-8731-f523beae4bd2,TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'type' of undefined på grund av: undefined.
>   CALLSTACK:: Error at t [as constructor]
>   (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2016-11-21.008/sp-client-base_sv-se_899e14970aaef71dbcbcd91de5d6b91f.js:48:11145)
>   at new t
>   (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2016-11-21.008/sp-webpart-base_sv-se_0ea5703a63ae7b404f2389ac7097d7ae.js:47:21019)
>   at Function.t.create
>   (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2016-11-21.008/sp-webpart-base_sv-se_0ea5703a63ae7b404f2389ac7097d7ae.js:47:21432)
>   at
>   https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2016-11-21.008/sp-webpart-base_sv-se_0ea5703a63ae7b404f2389ac7097d7ae.js:47:30960*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem is definately related to wrong version with spfx,
Reading [this information](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes-RC0) got me on the right track.

To anyone trying to get the sample to work, follow these steps:

**1. create a new spfx project(latest version)

2. copy files and folders into new project from sample

3. change \src\webparts\helloWorld\data-helpers\DataHelpersFactory.ts to this:**

```
import {
  IWebPartContext
} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { EnvironmentType } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import { IDataHelper } from './DataHelperBase';
import { DataHelperMock } from './DataHelperMock';
import { DataHelperSP } from './DataHelperSP';
export class DataHelpersFactory {
  public static createDataHelper(context: IWebPartContext): IDataHelper {
      return new DataHelperSP(context);
  }
}
```

**4. change \src\webparts\helloWorld\HelloWebPart.ts to this:**

```
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import styles from './TermSetRequester.module.scss';
import * as strings from 'helloWorldStrings';
import { IHelloWorldWebPartProps } from './IHelloWorldWebPartProps';
import { TaxonomyControl } from './controls/TaxonomyControl';
export default class HelloWorldWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IHelloWorldWebPartProps> {
  public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = '<div class="${styles.termSetRequester}"><div class="${styles.container}"></div></div>';
      const container: HTMLDivElement = this.domElement.querySelector('.' + styles.container) as HTMLDivElement;
      var termStoreCtrl = new TaxonomyControl(this.context);
      termStoreCtrl.render(container);
  }
  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }
  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**I got it to work in the 0365 workbench, as that was what I needed.**